# Why does a for loop have three parts?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, syntax, language-design

A typical `for` loop looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i){
    DoStuff();
}
```

As far as I can tell, the above is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < max;){
    DoStuff();
    ++i;
}
```

The aesthetic benefits of the three-part `for` loop are obvious. Are there any (obscure) **functional** benefits to a three-part `for` loop?

Comment: Your a-typical for-loop is nearly always used in loops where an iterator value is the result of something done to the container.

Comment: The `for` loop syntax is perfectly clear. It has an initializer, a terminating condition, and an increment for the loop counter. Every `for` loop requires those - why would you think it was better to confuse the issue?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can't make sense of your comment. "a-typical... nearly always..." sound contradictory. "the container" what container? After those two, I'm not sure how your comment applies here.

Comment: Note : If you have a container e.g. std::vector the best for loop to use doesn't even have 3 
parameters it will look (something) like this : `for (const auto& item : vector)`. It is called a [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and is the better option to use. (No index to go out of range).

Comment: Nearly always since you could write `for (;;true)` to create an infinite loop (thought that still has the three parts in a way). Note for infinite loops `while(true)` is the most used form.

Comment: Also your second example would usually be written with a while loop : `std::size_t i{0ul}; while (i<max) { DoStuff(); ++i; }`. You could say C++ programmers have a kind of common coding style culture here I guess;

Comment: @mbang Think iterators where something happens in the loop.

Comment: I doubt there was any aesthetic reasonig with the original for loop, it was just a construct that would fit in the (then "C") grammar and was easily to compile. So that became the syntax. And probably it is possible to do obscure stuff there as long as it works on the loop counter, but the intention is to almost always just use ++ or -- operations in the third part.

Comment: Re your last comment: you *can* do all sort of 'tricks' in the third statement of the `for` loop, like: `i += (i < max-1) ? 1 : 0` (to have the increment happen one less than the loop count) or `i += (i == max-1) ? 2 : 1` (to have it increment once more). But I'm not saying that's a *good* thing to do. (And the first example will likely result in an infinite loop!)

Comment: @AdrianMole I agree, we sometimes use this quote at work "Do not use tricks". It is always better to stay close to commonly accepted expressions/code constructs. 
If code starts to look "tricky" refactor, usually introduction of well named functions (even small ones) do wonders.

Comment: `continue;` is not usable in your alternative

Comment: @M.M if you wrote that verbatim as an answer, I would likely accept it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer   you could also write `for (;;)` for an infinite loop.   It has three parts - the only difference is that the first and third are empty statements, and the second [continuation condition] defaults to `true`

Comment: @Peter also true :)

Answer (score 2):

If a `continue;` directive is executed in a `for` loop, then the third clause **is** executed before execution resumes from the top.

So the "equivalent" is not exactly equivalent as a `continue;` here would skip the `i++` step.